# Screen is not updating its size after changing landscape to portrait orientation in iOS 16 using Xamarin forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, screen-orientation

I am using Xamarin forms.

When user navigates from one screen (which is in landscape mode) to Home Screen (which is in portrait mode), the view inside Home Screen is **not updating its size in iOS 16 only**.
For other screens, it is working fine.

There are 4 tabs on tab bar- Home Tab2, Tab3, Tab4 and More.

All screen except Tab4 should be in portrait mode and screen on Tab4 in Landscape mode.

When I launch app, I can see Home Screen which is in portrait mode.

When I click on Tab4, screen will rotate and I can see Tab4 screen in Landscape mode.

Now when I click on Home, then screen will rotate back to portrait mode but views inside are in Landscape mode. It’s not resizing as per portrait mode.

I am sharing screen shot for better understanding of exact issue.

[image]

[image]

I have used Carousel view, FlexLayout, Grid for UI design and data is dynamic from API response.

What changes needs to be done for this? Any hint for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Describe what should be different, in which image(s). Add all relevant code to question.

Comment: I have sorted this issue. I have added TextType as html for label in xaml file and that is causing this issue. Now I have removed it from xaml and added in Codebehind file.  Its working fine now.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. If you add "Your Answer" below, showing the details of the solution (including a snippet of code), that might help others in the future.

Comment: Sure. I have added solution below question.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution by @BSB. Moved from question to be an answer.]

```xml
    <Label x:Name="lblInformation" FontFamily="{StaticResource PrimaryFontNormal}"
                                   Padding="{OnIdiom Phone=20, Tablet=20}"
                                   FontSize="{OnIdiom Phone=14,Tablet=20}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="{OnIdiom Phone=Start, Tablet=Center}"
                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                   BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                   TextColor="White" />
```

Codebehind file:

```cs
    lblInformation.Text = user?.Information;
    lblInformation.TextType = TextType.Html;
```